# How to make Dump heap in android studio 3?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-studio-3.0

I connected device to my computer, open a new Android Profiler tab and run my application.

I see 3 graphics. 
Click to Record Memory allocation:
[image: red circle]
And after 2-3 seconds and lot of click in device (for testing) i click stop button:[image: gray square]

And...profiler closes, dump is not showing and my application is closed (withour error or any log with exception).

What i make wrong?

P.S.: In Android Device Monitor the behaviour is the same